# Which countries guarantee right to anonymous communication? Have there been court cases validating the right?

Tags: privacy, precedent, case-law, surveillance

I know many countries still have burner phones - i.e phones or SIM Cards which aren't tied to any identifiable person?

Are there countries which guarantee right to anonymous communication?

Are there countries which have tried to ban burner phones but courts have overturned the ban?

I know Germany doesn't allow anonymous SIM cards. Patrick Breyer filed a case against the ban but I think the courts refused to decide on the case, so I assume the [ban is still valid](https://www.patrick-breyer.de/en/no-right-to-anonymous-communications-european-court-of-human-rights-rubber-stamps-mandatory-sim-card-registration-laws/)

However, [it seems it's still allowed in most other European countries to buy an anonymous SIM Card](https://www.wikihow.com/Buy-a-Prepaid-Phone-in-Europe)

Have there been any other high profile countries which have tried to ban it but courts have overruled it?

Comment: Your subject line talks about anonymous communication, the body of the question is more specific to burner phones. Germany has the *Postgeheimnis*, and under most circumstances you can throw a letter into the mail and have it delivered unmolested. The letter may of course become evidence in a criminal case, and get dusted for fingerprints later on ...

Comment: @o.m. - I assumed it would be a general law about anonymous communication which would make Anonymous SIMs not bannable. Because I don't think any country has made a law specifically to allow anonymous SIM cards/burner phones.

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of countries with specific laws on the use of radio frequencies, often predating mobile phone technology and since updated, and other specific laws for letters and parcels.

Comment: @o.m. that's why I meant - any laws would predate cell phones & hence I didn't mention cellphones in the title.

Comment: Are you looking for this right to be over the general right to not be defamed or harassed?

Comment: @Jasen - I am looking for a law based on which Govt wouldn't be able to issue a blanket ban on all anonymous SIM cards

Comment: Goverment makes, and changes, laws, so it seems that you're looking for a country that protects this in their constitution.

Comment: @Jasen - no I am looking for laws also either made specifically for protecting privacy on cellphones or earlier laws which have been used to protect it.

Comment: How can an old law be greater than a new law?

Comment: @jasen - who said it can be or should be?

Comment: If a governent bans anonymnous sim cards they would do this by creating a new law.